# Python - How to get value of a key from position of dictionary inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

If i have a list of coordinates such as follows:

`coordinatestop = [{'x': 450, 'y': 0}, {'x': 630, 'y': -200}, {'x': 450, 'y': 200}, {'x': -450, 'y': 0}, {'x': -630, 'y': 200}, {'x': 450, 'y': -200}, {'x': -270, 'y': -200}, {'x': 270, 'y': -200}, {'x': -630, 'y': -200}]`

How would i go about getting or printing the value for the key 'x' of the dictionary in the first position of the list, in this case 450?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `print(coordinatestop[0]['x'])`?

Answer (score 1):

As your list contains dictionaries, calling any list's element is the same as calling a dictionary:

```
>>> print(coordinatestop[0])
{'x': 450, 'y': 0}
```

So you can refer to any list element as a dictionary:

```
coordinatestop[0]['x']
#or
coordinatestop[0].get('x')
```

--> First write the list index to call the dictionary, then the key of the dictionary to get its value.